# Redirect to Dynamic CRM Main page

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm developing a Dynamic CRM custom online authentication login. I'm able to retrieve the logged user information now i want to redirect the logged user to the CRM page. below is what I've got.

```
 // Now make an SDK call with the organization service proxy.
                // Display information about the logged on user.
                Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationProxy.Execute(
                    new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
                SystemUser systemUser = organizationProxy.Retrieve("systemuser", userid,
                    new ColumnSet(new string[] { "firstname", "lastname" })).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
                Response.Write("Logged on user is."+
                    systemUser.FirstName+" "+ systemUser.LastName);
```

Logged user information is retrieved successfully.how to redirect to the CRM main page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that:

```
Response.Redirect("http://<crmserver>:<portnumber>/main.aspx");
```

EDIT:
Check this options of Microsoft for doing what i think you want:

- [Single Sign-on from a Custom Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509057.aspx)
- [Implement Single Sign-on from an ASPX Webpage or IFRAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061.aspx)
- [Authenticate Users with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx)

Comment: still redirects to the login page. not to the main page

Comment: So you enabled IFD and you want a custom login, right? See my update.

Comment: yes i want the custom login and i have successfully done custom login authentication part. Stuck with redirection after the authentication.

Comment: I would check if the entered credentials are correct and if the connection is successful. Can you post your connection string?